# What is the meaning of the exponential operator $e^{H}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, definition

I am confused about this concept for a while. I guess for a Hamiltonian $$H=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c& d\end{pmatrix},$$ we would have $$e^{H}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{a} & e^{b}\\e^{c}& e^{d}\end{pmatrix}~?$$

But in another document I see it's defined by

[image: what I found in pdf somewhere]

Are they the same？Maybe this is a too basic question, but I have been confused for a long time.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential. They are _not_ the same: the first formula is incorrect (although the exponential of a diagonal matrix is the matrix consisting of the exponentials of its diagonal elements)

Comment: Your expression for $e^H$ in your first line is wrong.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Your formula for $e^H$ is right for diagonal H. Look at the MIT Open Courseware video [The Matrix Exponential](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwSk9M5lJx4)

Answer (score 1):

Just as functions (we consider we can) can be written as a power series,
$$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
where $x$ is a $c$ number. In the same way, we define the same function of an operator as
$$f(\Omega)=\sum_0^\infty a_n \Omega^n$$
which makes sense if the sum converges to some definite limit.

---

What you have written in the first line is wrong (in the general case). The definition given in the document is correct!
$$e^\Omega=\sum_1^\infty \frac{\Omega^n}{n!}$$
By going to the eigenbasis of $\Omega$ we can perform the sum
$$\Omega=\text{diag}(\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n)$$
$$\Omega^m=\text{diag}(\omega_1^m,\omega_2^m,\cdots,\omega_n^m)
$$
$$e^\Omega=\text{diag}\left(\sum_1^\infty \frac{\omega_1^m}{m!},\sum_1^\infty \frac{\omega_2^m}{m!},\cdots,\sum_1^\infty \frac{\omega_n^m}{m!}\right)$$
If the limits do converges this becomes
$$e^\Omega=\text{diag}(e^{\omega_1},e^{\omega_2},\cdots,e^{\omega_n})
$$

Comment: The sums after the horizontal line should start at $0$, not $1$.